# Type I Error in research: What is the alpha of a study especially when there are multiple comparisons?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons

In statistics class, we learnt that alpha = type 1 error rate, and type 1 error rate is the probability of wrongly rejecting our null hypothesis when it is true. It is equal to the red area of the following figure.[image]

However, very rarely do we have just ONE comparison in a study. For example, in a typical psychology study, we often produce something like this:
 [image]

I counted for you, there are 25 ANOVAs and 250 post hoc independent sample t-tests there... And as indicated by the researchers, they consider the p-value 0.05 to be significant. And if the researchers had used Bonferroni correction, I am afraid nothing would have been considered statistically significant...

Therefore, I want to know can I (or should I) calculate the overall Type 1 Error rate for a STUDY, but not just for a single test? Also, I want to know whether other methods to control for Type 1 Error rate exist.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm very happy to see non-statisticians come to this conclusion themselves! (+1) for critical thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia article here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem has more detail and several references.  Basically the Bonferroni is very conservative and there are several other options that are not as conservative.

Here are a couple of articles (medical area instead of psychology, but the principles still hold):

http://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(05)66461-6/fulltext

http://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(05)66516-6/fulltext

These articles give an overview and also discuss some of the cases where it is important to adjust and some where it may not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for when you say you want to 'calculate the overall Type 1 Error rate for a STUDY, but not just for a single test' is the 'False Discovery Rate'. There are numerous definitions of the false discovery rate, but Wikipedia is often a good start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate.

A false discovery rate will help to control the proportion of discoveries that are false, whereas the Bonferonni Correction will control for the probability of at least one false positive.